# android studio error :gradle project

Tags: android

android studio gave me this error :

Error:Failed to open zip file.
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

how can I solve this?

Comment: Check your app level build.gradle file. Make sure there is nothing wrong in there (no errors) and click the "Sync project with Gradle files" button in the toolbar in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Change your distribution url to

> http

instead of

> https
>
> distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

This worked in my case